# ReactTable is ordering elements vertically

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-table

I'm trying to use the 'react-table' library in my application. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong but all of the elements in the table appear vertically on the left side, and not in a grid. This was happening in my application, so I tried creating a new app to just display this table.

I copied this example word for word: [here](https://bitbucket.org/btillinghast/react-table-minimal-repo) The only difference is the data I hard coded two records.

This is what the page shows:

```
Name
Info
Stats
First Name
Last Name
Age
Status
Visits
Bret
Till
33
spoken for
4
```

Is there some CSS issue that's taking away inline or something? I'm new to react and even worse with CSS. I did remember to add this import:

```
import "react-table/react-table.css";
```

Here's a minimal repo that illustrates the issue:

[react-table-minimal-repo](https://bitbucket.org/btillinghast/react-table-minimal-repo)

Comment: can you inspect your table with the browser console to make sure the correct css rules are being applied

Comment: I guess I'm not really sure what to look for. I see the outer div gets the class "ReactTable -striped -highlight" like the example sets it.

Comment: Assuming your using webpacker or something along those line to transpile your css, how are you including the pack to your page? I would bet your not including the compiled css

Comment: I don't think I did. Does that mean I have to manipulate my webpack.config files? How do I do that? I did eject my project to be able to use css classes but I was just following a tutorial.

Comment: @Zip184, your issue will get a fast resolution if you provide a minimal repo. Do that and it would save you and others a lot of time

Comment: Can you please provide jsFiddle?

Comment: @TarunLalwani I added one. Thanks!

Comment: @Zip184 I can see the issue. The issue is you have create-react-app that you have ejected. When you build and server it is not serving the build directory. That is why it is not working

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Edit-1**

The issue with your project is setting `modules: true`, if you comment that out the project works

```
require.resolve('style-loader'),
{
  loader: require.resolve('css-loader'),
  options: {
    importLoaders: 1,
    // modules: true,
    localIdentName: '[name]__[local]__[hash:base64:5]'
  },
},
```

See below issue for more details

https://github.com/ant-design/babel-plugin-import/issues/166

**Original Answer**

The issue is because you have done mess after ejecting the project. I created a new project

```
react-create-app reacttable2
```

And the copied the src folder for of yours and everything worked fine

[image: Working app]

Comment: I want to use css modules though. I add the class styles like this "className={classes.StyleName}" throughout the rest of my application. Is there a way I can fix this while still using them?

Comment: I was just reading about it. I should probably just un-eject and do styles the normal way. Didn't realize assigning styles this way wasn't a usual practice.